# _ Invalid key code(s) for above character

Tags: java, awt, keyevent

i want send som underscore. but it replays a errors. says:

_ 
Invalid key code(s) for above character

this error was sendet from the default case:
default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);

my environment:

IntelliJ IDEA 2018.1 (Ultimate Edition)
JRE: 1.8.0_152-release-1136-b20 amd64
JVM: OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM by JetBrains s.r.o
Windows 10 10.0

BTW after i converted it now (28.4.2018 20:38) to kotlin i got the same error : https://gist.github.com/f61039faddaad67eaaf8c825f94934c4

the source:

```
import java.awt.*;
import java.awt.event.KeyEvent;
//
public class Keyboard {

  private Robot robot;

  public static void main(String... args) throws Exception
  {

    Keyboard keyboard = new Keyboard();
    keyboard.type("_");
  }

  public Keyboard() throws AWTException
  {
    this.robot = new Robot();
    robot.delay(500);
    robot.setAutoDelay(2);
    robot.setAutoWaitForIdle(true);
  }

  public Keyboard(Robot robot)
  {
    this.robot = robot;
  }

  public void type(CharSequence characters)
  {
    int length = characters.length();
    for (int i = 0; i < length; i++)
    {
      char character = characters.charAt(i);
      type(character);
    }
  }

  public void enter()
  {
    robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
  }

  public void type(char character){
    System.out.println(character);
    switch (character) {
      case '_': doType(KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE); break;
      default:
        throw new IllegalArgumentException("Cannot type character " + character);
    }
  }

  private void doType(int keyCode){
    try{
      robot.keyPress(keyCode);
      robot.keyRelease(keyCode);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Invalid key code(s) for above character");
    }
  }

  private void doType(int keyCode1, int keyCode2){
    try{
      robot.keyPress(keyCode1);
      robot.keyPress(keyCode2);
      robot.keyRelease(keyCode2);
      robot.keyRelease(keyCode1);
    }
    catch(Exception e){
      System.out.println("Invalid key code(s) for above character");
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Are there any tags you can add to this question (more than just "awt" "keyevent")?

Comment: '_' -> doType(KeyEvent.VK_SHIFT, KeyEvent.VK_MINUS)

Comment: java workaround pressing shift an minus (not KeyEvent.VK_UNDERSCORE ): https://gist.github.com/sl5net/900917ebdfc9ac316ab07f9d3c2bb2e6